# Can we get the data without submitting the form in case of CSRF Token via Postman

Tags: javascript, api, web-scraping, postman, csrf

I am fetching some data from a website by hitting the HTTP API via postman.
It was working fine for me but from last few days it's giving me an error i.e

> invalid csrf token 403

So as I inspect by developer tools in chrome.I  go to the network tab of the website and check the API.

> So now the site also sending the CSRF-Token in the header field.

So I know the API by which I can generate the csrf token.

I also get the token from API and sending the token with the header as they doing in the original site.

But I am wondering to know why every time the API returned with **invalid csrf token**

Is it possible to send CSRF token via postman. Becuase as I know about csrf token is used to stop the forgery request.
And the site has a form with the hidden field of csrf token and as the form is submitted the browser get the token from that hidden field and works like this.

**I want to know a few things:-**

> 1)Is it possible to send the csrf token in a header field via postman.
>   Or we must log in to the site via browser then only we can get the
>   data.
>
> 2)How can I get the data from the site using Postman?
>
> 3)Should I need to use some headless browser to achieve this?
>
> 4)As I go through with a post they are saying we need to set the
>   csrf-token in the cookie and then we can fetch the token from the
>   cookie and send the request.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normally CSRF Token implementation are tied with the session so make sure you are using the same session. Session will be created when you give a call to return a CSRF token.

If you are backend is using cookie for session implementation you can make a use of cookie interceptor in Post man to pass the same session cookie.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I am using the same session while fetching the CSRF and while fetching the data via CSRF. But still, it gives me an error of invalid CSRF token.
I am sending the token in the header field via postman like:-


CSRF-Token: cXEBdlsa-SHnQ2aCi2cIIyQ0yATr6xtxRO44

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is it possible to send the csrf token in a header field via postman? Or we must log in to the site via browser then only we can get the data.

You can get CSRF token from visiting website but send it via Postman. CSRF token, in many cases, does not depend on a website logging-in, only on the site visit.

> 2. How can I get the data from the site using Postman?

If a website returns CSRF in response headers, then you probably might use it within Postman.

If you need some other data - it depends on the website responses... I think you'll be able to get data provided your CSRF or/and other form data are correct.

> 3. Should I need to use some headless browser to achieve this?

Using browser automation is best since a browser manages all the session data, including cookies, headers, etc.

> 4. As I go through with a post they are saying we need to set the csrf-token in
>    the cookie and then we can fetch the token from the cookie and send the request.

Yes, the CSRF might be set or required by a server both in cookie and as a separate request header. So CSRF might be required (depending on website) in any the following:

- cookie header
- separate header
- form field

I'd recommend you to use a scripting language to work with CSRF (or analogs) for data fetching. An [example](https://webscraping.pro/submit-authenticated-form-session-cookie-python/) shows how to do it in Python.

### Note

That example will not work if the site **changes CSRF with each request/response**.